# Store received data in a Drupal CCK field or in aMySQL database table?

Tags: mysql, database, drupal

I want to store messages received from a server in some kind of database. My web site is based on Drupal and i am using Mysql database. The messages contain 6 field ( 2 strings and 4 integers). Upon storage these messages would be constantly queried for and also updated.

**Which approach should i go for here. A drupal CCK field or a MySql database table?**

Comment: How will the "messages" be getting into the database. That could affect the answer a bit. Are you creating an in-bound web service, parsing incoming email, ...?

Comment: @Matt:i ll be using socket connections to check for incoming messages.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. CCK's schema was designed more for flexibility than for being "constantly queried." If you don't expect your schema to change much over time and you have the ability to create and manage your own tables, you might not get much benefit from CCK. If you ever decide to export your data to a system other than Drupal, it would probably be easier from the simple table structure that you'd get from creating your own custom tables.

However, if you're in a hurry for some reason, you can probably create a single content type with the fields you describe in about 15 minutes. If you want support for the Views module, that's already included with CCK.

Comment: which one would give faster result on query and would be suitable for constant updates? Also which would be good in terms of memory usage. The number of items in this datatype could go upto more than 1000 in a day.

Comment: A custom table would almost certainly give you faster results. Only testing would tell you how much faster though. It might be negligible, it might not. The memory overhead would be less with a custom table too, since the data structure could be simpler. Again, I'm not sure by how much exactly though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have legacy data in a database, or have your database filled trough some external process, CCK is not an option. 
CCK allows you to modify fields in a web-interface; but, in doing so, you change the underlying database structure. 
CCK also depends on its own database structure, there is no way you can make CCK grab content from a legacy or none-CCK database, or to push content in there, without writing all the CCK fields yourself.